# Conditional replacement in columns - R

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

I would like to create a new column 'b' by subtracting a value 'z' from the existing column 'a'. However, where the values in the column 'a' are 0, I would like to keep them as 0.

I have tried the following where I create the new column y, and then ask the compiler to change the values in the new column back to 0 if their values are the same as 0-z.

I can't seem to get this to work as I get an error message

```
"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "b", value = c(66, 69, 71, 72, 66,  : 
  replacement has 55 rows, data has 16"
```

here is my data:

```
a
11
14
16
17
11
5
0
0
0
0
0
5
7
13
15
17
```

and here is my code:

```
z <- -55


data$y <- (0 - z)
data$b <- (data$a - z) 
data$b[data$y]<- 0
plot(data$b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is due to using `data$y` as an index. Instead, you need to compare `data$b` with `data$y`:

```
data$y <- (0 - z)
data$b <- (data$a - z) 
data$b[data$b == data$y] <- 0 # changed line
```

But you can create the new column `b` with a single command:

```
data$b <- data$a - z * as.logical(data$a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data$b = ieflse(data$a != 0, data$a - z, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="
a
11
14
16
17
11
5
0
0
0
0
0
5
7
13
15
17",header=T)

#assing z
z <- -55

#subtract with condition
df$b <- ifelse(df$a==0, df$a, df$a - z) 

#output
df
# a  b
# 1  11 66
# 2  14 69
# 3  16 71
# 4  17 72
# 5  11 66
# 6   5 60
# 7   0  0
# 8   0  0
# 9   0  0
# 10  0  0
# 11  0  0
# 12  5 60
# 13  7 62
# 14 13 68
# 15 15 70
# 16 17 72
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reproducible version of your data:

```
n <- 16
z <- -55
data <- data.frame(
  a = ifelse(runif(n) > 0.5, rnorm(n), 0)
)
```

You can use `ifelse` to provide different values for `b`, depending upon the value of `a`.  The `with` function lets you access variables inside a data frame, preventing you having to type `data` several times.

```
data$b <- with(data, ifelse(a == 0, 0, a - z))
```